# jQuery form validation: Return to default input field label when verification fails

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with default values in each input (such as Name, Email...) that successfully verifies inline when submit is clicked, thanks to your guys' great help so far (new to jQuery forms here).

One last issue is that in this form, if I enter incorrect values then hit submit, it shows an error icon next to each bad input but the bad text still remains in the form, and I'd like to have all rejected info be cleared out when submit is clicked (so the user is reminded what info to type in the input).

The following jQuery is meant to take care of this, but does nothing. Am I on the right path, at least? Invalid fields in the form have the `.incomplete` class applied to them.

```
$('.incomplete').submit(function() {
        var default_value = '';
        if ($(this).text() ==  !'') {
            $(this).text = '';
            }
    });
```

Full form code: http://pastie.org/4681942

Comment: What are you testing for in the `if` condition? I've never before seen (and don't immediately understand) what `($(this).text() == !'')` is meant to do.

Comment: also if you are trying to get or set the text of the input its not .text() its .val() in jQuery or .value in javascript.

Comment: Okay, made a few revisions. The if statement is to check if the length is not zero, and is meant to apply to only elements with the incomplete class (which have been marked invalid already). The intent is to target invalid inputs with data in them, and wipe their value if found.

Thanks for the help though. I realize my initial code was pretty problematic.

  `$('.incomplete').submit(function() {
   if ($(this).val().length !== 0) {
    $(this).val('');
    }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This jquery below does what I was looking to accomplish, but it only works the second time "submit" is clicked. On the first click, verification happens, and the second time the below code will clear the value of invalid fields.

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
            var e = $('.incomplete').length;
            if (e) {
                $('.incomplete').val('');
            };
        });
```

How can I get it to do both on the first click? Also updated pastie.